# How to clear an MDTextField without the hint_text in the wrong position

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I want to clear an `MDTextField`. The problem is when I set the `text` to `""`, the `hint_text` stays in the wrong position. (It happens when I try to clear while unfocused from the `MDTextField`)[image]

I tried to focus and then unfocus (from the code) on the text field to fix this, but it's not a good fix because on android the keyboard would come up. I also found this on the KivyMD documentation:

> When changing a `TextInput` property that requires re-drawing, e.g. modifying the `text`, the updates occur on the next clock cycle and not instantly. This might cause any changes to the `TextInput` that occur between the modification and the next cycle to be ignored, or to use previous values. For example, after a update to the text, changing the cursor in the same clock frame will move it using the previous text and will likely end up in an incorrect position. The solution is to schedule any updates to occur on the next clock cycle using `schedule_once()`.

Here's the code:

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

kv = Builder.load_string("""
<MainScreen>:
    orientation: "vertical"

    FloatLayout:
    
        MDTextField:
            id: textfield
            hint_text: "Text Fields"
            pos_hint: {"center_y":.5}
    
    Button:
        text: "Clear"
        on_press: root.clear_text_field()
""")


class MainScreen(BoxLayout):

    def clear_text_field(self):
        self.ids.textfield.text = ""


class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but shouldn't `self.ids.textfield.text` be written as `self.ids['textfield'].text`?

Comment: @jda5 Both ways work.